# Oracle SQL error by Primary key example !?

Tags: sql, oracle

I 'm learning  SQL, and I'm working with oracle SQL Dev. I have an example for the PRIMAR  Y KEY concept: 
here is the code

```
  drop table Dept;
  drop table Emp;
  -- creating a  Dept Table
  create Table Dept(
 Deptno  INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Dname VARCHAR(14),
  Loc varchar(13)
  );
  -- creating Emp Table
   create table Emp(
   Empno INTEGER NOT NULL,
   Ename VARCHAR(10),
   jobb VARCHAR(9),
   Mgr INTEGER,
   Hiredate DATE,
   Sal DECIMAL, 
   Comm DECIMAL,
   Deptno INTEGER NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT F_Emp FOREIGN KEY(Deptno) REFERENCES DEPT(Deptno),
   CONSTRAINT P_Emp PRIMARY KEY(Empno)
);
```

and here the error message that get, I don't understand what's exactly the error is ?

```
Error at Command Line:19 Column:56
 Error report:
 SQL Error: ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"
 *Cause:    A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement
       gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary
       key constraint in the referenced table.
*Action:   Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS
       catalog view
```

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The department table requires a primary key on it on the DeptNo column to reference it as a FK constraint on the Emp table.

(Yes, Oracle could be a bit more useful on the error message to say the least)

Comment: should I make the DEptNo as primary key ?? or what

Comment: Most likely, unless it is not primary.

Comment: @Andrew - I disagree, for once this is one of the more useful error messages. It tells you the exact point in the script where it fails which is the creation of the FK. The cause states exactly the issue - "no matching unique or primary key constraint in the referenced table" where unique and/or primary are the key words.

Comment: @Zammalad - and naming the FK constraint, or specifying which table is missing the PK would not be more helpful? of course it would, but Oracle does not do that.

Comment: @Andrew : Line:19 Column:56 - DEPT(Deptno) and "referenced table" can only be DEPT given it is the referenced table in that constraint. All the information is there granted not in an textbook formatted essay but simply put, you don't need that.

Comment: @Zammalad Only because the table references a single other table -- if it had two columns or more referencing other tables it would not tell you which one did not have a primary key.

Answer (score 3):

This is because a foreign key must link to either a unique dataset which can be made up by either a primary key or a unique constraint property. You can link multiple columns in the foreign key but again the reference data must be unique.

In your case the easiest method would be to make the `Deptno` a primary key in `Dept` by changing the table creation to:

```
create Table Dept(
  Deptno  INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Dname VARCHAR(14),
  Loc varchar(13),
  CONSTRAINT P_Dept PRIMARY KEY(Deptno)
);
```

For cases where you don't want the FK referencing a PK you can create a unique constraint on the field that you want in the reference table. To begin with the first thing which must be done is it must have the `NOT NULL` constraint specified on the reference column in the reference table. Then it is a case of adding `CONSTRAINT const_name UNIQUE (col_name)` to the reference table to enforce unique values.

As an example. Lets assume you wanted to link to a phone number. So We could alter your example as follows:

```
drop table Dept;
drop table Emp;
-- creating a  Dept Table
create Table Dept(
  Deptno  INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Dname VARCHAR(14),
  Loc varchar(13),
  TelNo INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT tel_no_uq UNIQUE (TelNo)
);
-- creating Emp Table
create table Emp(
  Empno INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Ename VARCHAR(10),
  jobb VARCHAR(9),
  Mgr INTEGER,
  Hiredate DATE,
  Sal DECIMAL, 
  Comm DECIMAL,
  Deptno INTEGER NOT NULL,
  TelNo INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT F_Emp_Tel FOREIGN KEY(TelNo) REFERENCES DEPT(TelNo),
  CONSTRAINT P_Emp PRIMARY KEY(Empno)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

A Google search came up with this [Oracle/PLSQL: ORA-02270 Error](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora02270.php) which leads me to believe that a table call DEPT does not exist that has a primary key column called Depto, and that is causing the error. I hope this is helpful.

EDIT:I do not believe you can set a oracle recursive foreign key until the table has been created, at which point you will need to ALTER the table to add the recursive key.